# Android USB reverse tethering: How to fool the apps

Tags: android

USB reverse tethering = Cellphone gets network connection from PC via USB.

I know how to do USB reverse tethering except for one problem: Many Android apps will check network connection using the code below before doing any useful work:

```
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo info = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
```

The problem is that, when using USB reverse tethering, the above code will report no network connection. However, there IS a network connection (which is the USB reverse tethering itself), and ping, wget and all programs not doing this stupid check work well.

So the question is: How can I hack the system to let this network connection check return success (so that I can fool these apps)?

BTW. I use Cyanogenmod 7. And any solution specific to this MOD is also welcome.

Comment: Are you trying to make an application for this, or just just looking for an modification to the android system to do this? Since I don't think that from the java code perspective there's much you can change to make the whole system think it's connected.

Comment: user717572: It's the best if we can dynamically adjust runtime parameters. Otherwise, I think we may have to modify the system. Any applicable solution is welcome.

Comment: does your application initiate the reverse tethering or is it a 3rd party thing?

Comment: can you bring up a fake interface?

Comment: If already running, well made apps may react to an intent with action `android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE`. Broadcasting this if your app makes internet available could trick some apps into using it. However, most apps will query `ConnectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo()` which will still answer 'not connected' most likely.

Comment: Can you just enable cell data or wifi? Even though the interface wouldn't actually be connected (assuming there's no activated SIM installed) it may be enough to change the network state.

Comment: This is probably what you're looking for http://blog.mathieu.carbou.me/post/60454997009/reverse-usb-tethering-with-android-22 There is also this project: http://www.codeproject.com/kb/android/usbportforwarding.aspx And also an app on the Android market (paid, with free trial): https://market.android.com/details?id=com.littlelan.ReverseTether.Trial

Comment: I think this works well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18401704/reverse-tethering-android

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing this much hacking I am assuming that you will probably have your device rooted.  If so program a shell interface to send commands to the device shell with JNI and receive STDOUT.  Use this interface to run a netcfg command that can be parsed into an array - this will give you all the details the API hides.  It also allows you to override Androids device settings using the ipconfig command.

As far as using this to send and receive from your device - in my experience - you will have to probably compile a device specif module that can be loaded into the kernel at run time.  Or just download the kernel from the manufacturer and compile the module into the kernel and then flash the phone with the new custom kernel.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

To do this , you have to download ReverseTethering_3.19.zip file (Google it to find the link.) 
Extract to your desired location.

**Prerequisite**: -

1. only rooted phones work.
2. USB debugging should be enabled.

Now connect your rooted android mobile to PC through USB cable.Wait for PC to recognize your mobile. Now open the extracted zip file and open ***AndroidTool.exe*** with admin rights.

Now click connect in the android tool.

Now it tries to connect and installs USB tunneling apk on your device.It also asks for super user rights . Grant it.

Finally after successfully establishing the connection, you will see.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B11p07T8VxhNNUdIM3gtTFR4N3M/view?usp=sharing
(Sorry, I cant upload image.)

Now you get the internet on your mobile and  usb tunneling app is installed.But you can access only HTTP connections(i.e;) works only in chrome. Play store apps may not work.

So you have to fool apps and make it believe that either is mobile is connected to WiFi or mobile data . Only then apps work.

So you have to go to Tools menu in Android tool.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B11p07T8VxhNRXR3aTVUZUl1dVk/view?usp=sharing

Now install hack(optional).It installs Xposed framework and installs hack connectivity apk. Just follow the instructions , it is easy.
Hack connectivity makes the apps believe that mobile is connected to WiFi or mobile data  depending on which type of hack u did after installing Hack connectivity. Finally after hacking ,it asks for reboot. After reboot , you can enjoy internet using USB reverse tethering on all apps.

Comment: Link to 'So you have to go to Tools menu in Android tool' is dead.